# Where's Gtk# 2.12.22 for Windows?

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I want to install MonoDevelop on my Windows computer

The MonoDevelop website directs me to download GtkSharp 2.12.20
No good - MonoDevelop 4.0.13 requires 2.12.22

When I go to the Mono website, the installer is out of date at 2.12.11
When I got to the Gtk Sharp website, the installer is out of date at 2.12.20

Am I having a brain fart? Where can I get this installer from?

Comment: Move it, don't close it..

Comment: It seems people 21 peope who upvoted this and 52 on answer do not agree with 5 people who closed this question!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I had the same problem but I found the link to download it:

http://download.xamarin.com/GTKforWindows/Windows/gtk-sharp-2.12.22.msi

Regards.

Comment: Other versions can be accessed via that URL too (eg. 2.12.26.msi)  This helps me, as I'd removed some of the installers in a cleaning spree, but it seems you need the installer to uninstall.. :s

Comment: xamarin is bought by Microsoft and as usual the first thing they do, destroy it. Now you can download GTK# from [mono-project download page](http://www.mono-project.com/download/)